# Best ways to transfer Euros from French bank to Indian bank

Tags: india, france, money, internet

Recently, I moved from Paris, France to  Ahmedabad, India. I have bank account in Credit Agricole in France and SBI, ICICI in India.

**I would like to transfer euros from my French bank to Indian bank through electronically. What is the cheapest and safe way to transfer this money to Indian bank ?**

I do not have time constraints (i.e., I can wait for 1 month also, if this transfer takes time). My only concern is that it should be cost effective.

Comment: People, when voting to close a question, especially from a new user, it really is polite to tell them why.

Comment: Pankesh, the problem people have with the question is probably that it's not about travelling. It's about banking and finance and a bit about immigrating/emigrating/relocating. The question would better suit our sister site, **[Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com)**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on the Personal Finance & Money stackexchange site instead

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to transfer money is to use a FX Money Broker. Once your account is set up with them, you can transfer the money to them and then to your final account.

I would recommend locating a broker in Europe as they will be regulated by EU and country laws. It will be cheaper than using your bank's exchange rate when making a transfer.